# Get Email from Name using workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013 Online and I need to get the email address using the name of the person.

A single text field had the user name in it and using that, I need to retrieve the email address of the person using a **WORKFLOW**

Is that possible OOTB?

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do is, send email to the person listed in the text field *(Name format: Lastname, Firstname)*. It works for single person. But if there are more than one person, the workflow fails. Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: what are you storing in text field? display name or login name?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor Display name

Comment: you can get user profile properties by login name http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: I want to do using a workflow, if it is possible. See my edit for the detailed issue

Comment: you can call REST API from workflow as well. https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: I'm not able to call the rest api. I tried it from the browser and it gives me 400 Bad Request. https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/coll/subsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Reports’)

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow designer you can set variables by querying the User Profiles as the data source. This needs the Account Name to search on.

To do this:
1. Choose Action "Set Workflow Variable".

2. Create Workflow Variable "Email".
3. Click fx on Value. Set Data Source as User Profiles. The rest you should be able to work out.

[image: WF Variable set through User Profile]

Comment: How to query user profile as data source? You have any links?

Comment: See Improved answer, this is from my knowledge as opposed to links I have followed.

Comment: Since you can only find the user profile by account name, even if you can parse your single text field into a user name (e.g. find the comma and use the first initial of the first name and the whole last time), this won't work for multiple users in one text field.

Comment: @ErinL Good point, user added this as an edit to the question in between writing my answer and refreshing the page!